# Adding filetype to IIS7 with web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I want to allow my website to serve up .WOFF files.  Initially I tried a command line prompt in my installer but it didnt seem to work then I found out I could add this in `web.config`.  Unfortunately when I do this the server stops serving up most other file types (css / js etc)

What is happening?

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem in the past and it was due to the fact that the ".woff" extension was already mapped in the machine.config, causing a silent conflict.

Try using the "remove" tag just before the "mimeMap" tag, like this:

```
<remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
```

That should fix your problem, at least it did for me.

Comment: I'm having similar errors when adding items to sites.  Where is this machine.config - and more to the point, **why** does it have mappings that do no earthly good?  I've had to add phantom REMOVEs to things like SSI handlers, with similar symptoms.  Does machine.config have every possible thing mapped but disabled?  And if so, what _earthly_ use is the IIS Manager, when using the configuration options breaks things>